# What is the optimal RAM (DDR4) speed for a Ryzen 7 1800x CPU?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, ddr

I am in the process of ordering parts to build a computer, and I am completely confused with what kind of RAM I should get. My motherboard is an MSI B350 Tomahawk Plus (pay attention to the Plus, since the QVL's of both boards differ). From what I understand, the RAM has to be compatible with both the CPU and the motherboard. Is this correct?

And what if the DDR4 is neither on the motherboard QVL and the mobo is not the the RAM manufacturer QVL? I am asking this because this RAM is not cheap, but it has a reasonable price:

https://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231977

What would prevent it from working with my setup?